# Cant find the actual struct in sqlite

Tags: c, sqlite

I am searching for the full definition of "struct sqlite3_stmt" in sqlite 3 source code but cant find it anywhere. I am stumped !

Only thing I found is : typedef struct sqlite3_stmt sqlite3_stmt;

What C sorcery is this ?

Comment: It'll probably be an opaque type, so its definition will be in a C *source* file somewhere, rather than a header.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279683/never-defined-structure

Answer (score 1):

This link: [Never defined structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279683/never-defined-structure) addresses the particular implementation in SQLite3, and is an interesting read.

I will just describe what happens here from the point of view of the C language.

if you write:

```
struct sqlite3_stmt;
```

You tell the compiler that there is a structure named `sqlite3_stmt` that exists somewhere in your translation units or in another library. That symbol will be resolved at link-time if a matching definition exists.

Please note that the compiler does not know its *size*, therefore it can only be accessed as a pointer, like this:

```
struct sqlite3_stmt * ptr_totstmt; /* OK */
```

This however will give you an error:

```
struct sqlite3_stmt stmt; /* error: storage size of 'stmt' isn't known */
```

Also, you must prefix the pointer declaration with the keyword `struct`, else the compiler can't solve the symbol:

```
sqlite3_stmt * ptr_totstmt; /* error: unknown type name 'sqlite3_stmt' */
```

The intent of the `typedef` here is to add syntactic sugar so the user of the type does not have to care whether he is using a struct.

```
typedef struct sqlite3_stmt sqlite3_stmt;

sqlite3_stmt * ptr_totstmt; /* OK */
```

So really, for the compiler, `struct sqlite3_stmt` and `sqlite3_stmt` are two different things, the latter conveniently being an alias for the former.

The "magic" here is that as long as the `struct sqlite3_stmt` type or its alias are only used to instanciate pointers, its size never needs to be known, only the size of a pointer for the target system. The linker effectively does not even bother trying resolving them, since pointers are nothing but values representing an address in memory.

So here, the `struct sqlite3_stmt` is never implemented anywhere in SQLite3's code, it is just really accessed as a pointer and cast to whatever "real" type the implementation expects.